# How to calculate the integral from the square of defined function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, integral

I have a problem with calculating the integral in Python.

So, I have defined function:

```
def function_f(x):
    if x>=0 and x<=1: 
        return ((1/3)**x)
    else:
        return 0
```

I know to calculate the simple one (without square), with this code:

```
from scipy import integrate
integrate.quad((function_f), 0, 1)
```

But the problem is that I need to calculate the **integral from the square of this function**, so I need integral from (function_f)^2.

I hope that you have some advices how I can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not used to scipy.integrate, but based on your explanations you should be able to do :

```
integrate.quad(lambda x:function_f(x)**2, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) Do you know maybe how can I calculate the integral from the complex function?

Comment: @Minimalist Which complex function ?

Comment: @Minimalist if you're ok with an approximation, you may always approximate an integral using the sum of dy*dx (but I'm sure scipy have this already built somewhere)